# PHP Autoload with spl_autoload_register in a sub folder

Tags: php, namespaces, spl

My directory structure is something like below

```
> Root
> -Admin // admin area
> --index.php // admin landing page, it includes ../config.php
> -classes // all classes
> ---template.php 
> ---template_vars.php // this file is used inside template.php as $template_vars = new tamplate_vars();
> -templates // all templates in different folder
> --template1
> -index.php
> -config.php
```

in my config.php file i have used

```
<?php
.... // some other php code
spl_autoload_register(NULL, FALSE);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

classes\template::setTemplate('template/template1');
classes\template::setMaster('master');
 .... // some other php code
?>
```

I have set the proper namespaces (only in classes) and in my index.php on root I access the classes

```
<?php 

require 'config.php';
$news_array = array('news1', 'news1'); // coming from database

$indexTemplate = new \classes\template('index');
$indexTemplate->news_list = $news_array; // news_list variable inside index template is magically created and is the object of template_vars class
$indexTemplate->render();
?>
```

So far it is working perfect, it renders the template and populate the template vars,

but when I open index file in admin folder, it gives following error

> Fatal error: Class 'classes\template_vars' not found in
>   /home/aamir/www/CMS/classes/template.php on line 47

any idea how to fix this thing. It works on root, but from inside admin panel it doesnot work

Comment: Somehow this code hurts me when I read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a trick for that:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../');
```

Before you include `../config.php` **OR**

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/');
```

Inside `config.php`

Comment: thanks for the tip, I have added `set_include_path` inside the config.php because i don't want to edit 100+ files, and now it works fine. THANKX

Comment: Ah yes, using `__DIR__` inside `config.php` would do the trick as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem (on windows) and i think i can explain the matter.

For instance let's take two simple scripts, the first one creates a class in a `namespace` called `root` in a dir called `root`:

-`root\sampleClass.php`:

```
namespace root;

class sampleClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }

    public function getNameSpace()
    {
        return __NAMESPACE__;
    }
}
```

and the second script located here `root\index.php` and contains only those two lines :

```
spl_autoload_register();
$o = new sampleClass;
```

then if you run the `root\index.php` script you will get a FATAL error like this:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class sampleClass could not be loaded in C:\wamp\www\root\test.php on line 4
```

And if you remove the namespace keyword on the `root\sampleClass.php`, the error vanish.

So I won't conclude anything about the demeanor of the core php because i am not a php core dev but something like this happen:

If you don't specify a namespace the `spl_autoload_register();` function will also look in the current dir (which is `root\`) and find the class called `sampleClass.php` but if you specify a namespace like `root` in our example the `spl_autoload_register();` function will try to load a file located somewhere like "root\root".

So at this point you have two solutions :

**1)** first which is not proper is to create a subdir called `root` which also contains the `sampleClass.php`

**2)** second which is better is to add a kind of trick in the `index.php` script :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.realpath('..'));
```

which will tell the `spl_autoload_register()` function to check in the parent dir.

That's all